# How to pass parameter to a escaping function that calls escaping function in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function, escaping, closures

```
func fetchParseNSyncJson2(parseNSyncFunction: @escaping(String)->Void) {
    if 200 == 200 {
        print("Got the json")
        parseNSyncFunction("The json data")
    }
}

func parseNSync2(jsonDictionary: String) {
    print("Parsed the data: \(jsonDictionary)")
}

fetchParseNSyncJson2(parseNSyncFunction: parseNSync2(jsonDictionary:))
```

Above code works fine but I want to add another parameter to ***parseNSync2*** function that escapes a closure block, like this

```
func parseNSync2(jsonDictionary: String, done: @escaping(Bool)->Void {
    print("Parsed the data: \(jsonDictionary)")
}
```

Then I want to pass this new function [image: new function] (***with escaping block***) in fetchParseNSyncJson2 function just like I did above, [image: I did this above] how can I do that ??

Here is a what I have tried (note: code below contains errors)

```
func fetchParseNSyncJson(parseNSyncFunction: (json: String, done: (Bool)->Void)) {
    if 200 == 200 {
        print("got the json")
        
        parseNSyncFunction(json: "json data", done: (_:)) // how should i pass parameter here??
    }
}

func parseNSync(_ jsonDictionary: String, done: @escaping (Bool)->Void) {
    print("Parsed: \(jsonDictionary)")
}

fetchParseNSyncJson(parseNSyncFunction: parseNSync(json:, done: { done in // how to i pass parameter here
                                                        if done {
                                                            print("Done")
                                                        }
}))
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. What parameter do you want to pass? Perhaps you could rewrite your question to use simpler and more distinct function names. As written it is quite hard to follow. You can't avoid the escaping parameter since the closure is escaping.

Comment: ok so how do I pass it?

Comment: Pass *what*?  I can't follow what your problem is

Comment: pass the escaping parameter i.e: done,

func parseNSync2(jsonDictionary: String, done: @escaping(Bool)->Void {
    print("Parsed the data: \(jsonDictionary)")
}

I want to pass this in fetchParseNSyncJson2 function. Kindly check the sample code.

Comment: Repeating the same thing isn't helping. What parameter? The `done` closure? It is just called `done`.  Do you mean `done(true)`?

Comment: I have clarified the question above, lets see if that helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234739/discussion-between-paulw11-and-rehan-ali-khan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can try -

```
import Foundation

typealias DoneBlock = ((_ success: Bool) -> Void)
typealias ParseNSyncBlock = ((_ json: String, _ done: @escaping DoneBlock) -> Void)

func fetchParseNSyncJson(parseNSyncBlock: @escaping ParseNSyncBlock) {
    if 200 == 200 {
        print("got the json")
        parseNSyncBlock("the json", { success in
            print("success : \(success)")
        })
    }
}
func parseNSync(_ json: String, _ done: @escaping DoneBlock) {
    print("Parsed: \(json)")
    done(true)
}

fetchParseNSyncJson(parseNSyncBlock: parseNSync)
```

Output

```
got the json
Parsed: the json
success : true
```

Comment: fetchParseNSyncJson(parseNSyncBlock: parseNSync(_:, _: { success in
                                                        if success {
                                                            
                                                        }
} ))

is it possible to define the completion block outside ??

At calling place?

Comment: You can define the completion block body only at the call site of the function, when you are actually calling/invoking the function. In the answer, when you are passing `parseNSync` function as parameter, you are not calling it here, it's being called from inside the function that accepts it. So the answer to your question in "No". You can't do this  while using a function reference like you intend.